# SQL Update with 0 if no match

Tags: ms-access

I want to take the below SQL and if there is no update found, I want to add a 0 in that record. Is this possible from a single query? Currently I utilize this query to update records and then go back and run a query to add 0 in null fields.

```
UPDATE tbl_shortage_report 
LEFT JOIN tbl_temp_shortage_report 
ON  (tbl_shortage_report.Plant =     tbl_temp_shortage_report.Plant) 
AND (tbl_shortage_report.Material = tbl_temp_shortage_report.Material) 
SET tbl_shortage_report.Quantity_Open_Req = [tbl_temp_shortage_report].[Quantity_Open_Req]
WHERE (((tbl_temp_shortage_report.Quantity_Open_Req) Is Not Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be:

```
UPDATE tbl_shortage_report 
LEFT JOIN tbl_temp_shortage_report 
ON  (tbl_shortage_report.Plant =     tbl_temp_shortage_report.Plant) 
AND (tbl_shortage_report.Material = tbl_temp_shortage_report.Material) 
SET tbl_shortage_report.Quantity_Open_Req = IFNULL([tbl_temp_shortage_report]. [Quantity_Open_Req],0)
```

Comment: I should note I am using Access 2016 as a front end and I tried that, I apologize for not noting that earlier. It tells me that IFNULL is not a valid function and I found that I can use IIF(ISNULL(column),0,column) with Access but I wanted to see if it's possible in standard SQL.

Comment: IFNULL is a myql function. You have tagged your question with mysql that's why I gave mysql solution. You should have tagged in MSAccess if you expect correct solution

Comment: You are correct, it was completely my fault, I do apologize.

Comment: Use Nz() or maybe better an IIf() instead of IFNULL(). `IIf([field] Is Null, 0, [field])`